# jQuery DataTables: localize "Entries", move "Prev/Next", enable ThemeRoller

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

could anyone please answer my 3 DataTables-related questions?

I'm trying to use DataTables [in the PHP script](http://preferans.de/top20.php) displaying weekly players of my game in Russian language, but:

[image]

1. I can't find the option for localizing the **Showing 1 to 20 of 3,558 entries** string
2. My buttons for **First Next 1 2 3 4 5 Prev Last** are way too the right in MSIE 7 and Chrome and even make the horizontal scrollbar appear, how could I move them to the left a bit? In Firefox 3.6.15 the page looks completely broken :-(
3. How do you enable the jQuery UI ThemeRoller support?

For the last item I've tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#rating").dataTable( {
                "bJQueryUI": true,
```

but it hasn't produced the nice looking table.

Thank you for your help!
Alex

Comment: Without stating the obvious maybe the Datatables forum would yield quicker results :)

Comment: Ok, I've donated and asked there too: http://datatables.net/forums/comments.php?DiscussionID=4530

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer #3:

You have already enabled ThemeRoller Support with that option; but all the option does is enable the ability to add jQuery UI-specific classes to your table.

With the classes added, you still need to reference a jQuery UI stylesheet (sample below; yours will be different).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom-folder-name/jquery-ui-1.8.8.custom.css" />
```

Themeroller themes will also have a bunch of images that are a part of the theme, located as a subfolder of custom-folder-name. You don't necessarily need everything the ThemeRoller package produces, so you can sort of pick and choose; or keep the whole directory intact and only reference what you need. It's just a few bytes on the server to keep the unused stuff in place!

The sample seems to be cut a bit short, so you might already be doing this-- but don't forget that the last item of the initialization can't have a comma after it.

Comment: Thank you, gregp! I've added the @import "/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.css"; line and now my script looks better ( at http://preferans.de/top20.php ) and it isn't broken in FF anymore. However #1 is still valid and I have the NEW BIG PROBLEM of the "First Next 1 2 3 4 5 Prev Last" buttons being congested in all 3 browsers.

Comment: Alexander, another quick thing you will want to do is add the class "display" to your table. So, your table tag will look like:

'<table id="rating" class="display" width="100%"...etc...>'

This will fix the position of your sort icons, and may end up fixing other layout issues as well.

Answer (score 1):

To answer #1 :

Maybe you can view following link

[How to use DataTables internalisation options](http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/i18n)